# Running a thread in Zygote process will block emulator launching?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to add an single thread in zygote process to do some monitor work. The thread's runnable entry is something as below.

```
public void run() {
     //monitor logic here
     Thread.sleep(5*1000);
}
```

I run it on emulator. However, it will block emulator's running, and emulator is always in its launching UI.
would anyone explain why? and how to resolve it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you checked logcat?

Comment: Seems there is no log printed after starting to run this thread.

Comment: sorry, I filtered some log before. There is one suspicious log which is  "WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms"